# Stop google indexing subdomain

Tags: robots.txt, google-index

I have subdomain "klient" for testing websites for our clients and I don't want that to be indexed. I have set in robots.txt (in root of our web) this:

```
User-agent: *
disallow: /subdom/klient/*
```

But I'm not sure, if it does really work, because I have now found testing site in google results...

Where could be problem or how could we stop google and other bots indexing this folder...?

Thank you

Comment: Is it a subdomain or a subdirectory?

Comment: It is subdirectory, based in ./subdom/klient/ and with .htaccess, it is accessible like subdomain (klient.url.com)

Comment: From Google's perspective it is a subdomain, not a subdirectory.

Comment: @JohnKugelman yeah you are right... So what is right solution to go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How robots.txt file should be properly written for subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320228/how-robots-txt-file-should-be-properly-written-for-subdomains)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do that by placing a `robots.txt` in the root directory of your subdomain.

So in your `klient.example.com`, place a `robots.txt` with the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

If you want to remove already indexed pages, create a new webconsole site with your subdomain and remove the indexed pages there.

Comment: And will this affect all folders in this subdomain? Because the structure is for every client like this: klient.3angle.cz/ourClient/

Comment: yes, this will affect all folders in subdomain.
so:
klient.3angle.cz/ourClient/ 
klient.3angle.cz/ourClient2/
klient.3angle.cz/newClient/
And every other folder and subfolder in klient.3angle.cz will get affected.